# Package build fails on R 3.6.0 (devel) but not on 3.5.5 (release)

Tags: r, travis-ci

I am writing a package for CRAN, which I test on Travis on release and development versions. The package builds fine on the release version and gives this error on devel:

```
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
ERROR: hard-coded installation path: please report to the package maintainer and use ‘--no-staged-install’
* removing ‘/tmp/RtmpZ9RX7i/Rinst63414089e04b/PackageName’
      -----------------------------------
ERROR: package installation failed
```

The change in code that caused the build to fail and that relate to a hard-coded path are these lines in the package:

```
k_extdata <- "extdata"
k_package <- "PosteriorBootstrap"
k_german_credit <- "statlog-german-credit.dat"

data_file <- function(name) {
  return(system.file(k_extdata, name, package = k_package))
}
```

and these lines in the tests:

```
stan_file <- data_file("bayes_logit.stan")
bayes_logit_model <- rstan::stan_model(file = stan_file)
```

An online search reveals zero results for this problem. Has anyone found this before, and why does it fail only in the devel version?

Comment: Please read https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2019/02/14/staged-install/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is triggered by the new *Staged Install* feature introduced in R 3.6.0. You can read more about this on the official R blog: https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2019/02/14/staged-install/index.html

Comment: can you add a little more detail so that this answer remains useful if the link breaks in the future?